# Why can't supervisor find command source

Tags: bash, supervisord

The following is my `supervisor.conf`.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:daphne]
command=source "/opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh" && daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 robot_configuration_interface.asgi:channel_layer

[program:worker]
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="robot_configuration_interface.settings"
command= source "/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" && django-admin runworker
```

This is the error I get:

> INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'source'

Shouldn't the bash have the command source. If this is using `sh` how can I force it to run bash?

Comment: `.` is the POSIX-compliant synonym for `source`.

Comment: That said, it doesn't look like supervisord invokes a shell at all here. If that's correct, and it's directly exec'ing a command, then you simply **can't** use shell idioms and commands at top level.

Comment: To be clear, supervisor uses [the Python `shlex` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) to perform shell-like parsing. Reading the docs and/or source to same should provide a pretty good idea of what it can and can't do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Supervisor does not start a shell at all, either `bash` *or* `sh` -- so it's no surprise that it can't find shell-builtin commands. If you need one, you're obliged to start one yourself. Thus:

```
command=/bin/bash -c 'source "$0" && exec "$@"' /opt/ros/indigo/setup.sh daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 robot_configuration_interface.asgi:channel_layer
```

and

```
command=/bin/bash -c 'source "$0" && exec "$@"' /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash django-admin runworker
```

In both these cases, the `exec` is present to tell the shell to replace itself in-memory with the process it's executing rather than leaving a shell instance that does nothing but wait for that process to exit.

The first argument after `bash -c` is placed in `$0`, and subsequent ones after that are placed in `$1` and onward; thus, we can source `"$0"` and execute `"$@"` to refer to the first such argument and then those subsequent to same.

---

From [the docs](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment):

> **No shell is executed by supervisord when it runs a subprocess**, so environment variables such as USER, PATH, HOME, SHELL, LOGNAME, etc. are not changed from their defaults or otherwise reassigned.

Thus, shell operations (including `&&`) similarly cannot be expected to be usable at top level.

Answer (score 9):

I also encounter this problem.

And I found a better solution.

Using `source ~/.bash_profile` maybe better.

```
[program: dapi]
user=pyer
command=/bin/bash -c 'source ~/.bash_profile  && /usr/local/python3.6/bin/pipenv run python manage.py'
directory=/data/prd/tools/dapi
autostart=true
startretries=1
stopasgroup=true
```

If the process started by supervisor created subprocesses, maybe can ref: 
http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#pidproxy-program

Comment: Better for your use case, maybe. The OP explicitly wanted to source a different (`setup.sh`) program. `.bash_profile` is intended for *login shells* -- a daemon is not a login shell -- so it'll often contain contents appropriate for interactive use, not for services.